# How to get tables from .mdb using meza?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using meza to read .mdb (MSAccess database) files.

```
from meza import io  

try:
    self.data = list(io.read_mdb(self.db_path, table=self.table))
except TypeError as e:
    raise
```

io.read_mdb returns generator object (if table param is specified it returns all rows from specified database if not from first). However - it also prints all table names to the console when I ran this code snippet.

QUESTION:
Is there a way how to fetch all table names with meza?
or
Is there a way how to catch 'unwanted' tables console output?

i tried this, but without success:

```
with open(here_path + os.sep + "temp.txt", "w") as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        try:
            x = list(io.read_mdb(path))
        except TypeError as e:
                raise
```

Then I would just read tables from file temp.txt

**EDIT:**

edit based on reubano answer:

```
def show_tables_linux(path):
    tables = subprocess.check_output(["mdb-tables", path])
    return tables.decode().split()
```

above function returns list of tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off using the [`mdbtools`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/) command `mdb-tables`.

`mdb-tables test.mdb`